# Equivalence of verma modules

Tags: lie-algebras, verma-modules

Let $R^+$ be the set of positive roots and $L_\alpha$ the root space to $\alpha \in R^+$. $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of L.

Let $I_\lambda$ be the left ideal of $U(L)$ which is generated by elements of the form $X \in L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in R^+$ and of the form $H-\lambda(H)$ with $H\in \mathfrak{h}$.

We define the Verma module

$$V(\lambda)=\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})/I_\lambda$$

Let $F_\lambda$ be the one-dimensional F-vector space for $L_+=\oplus_{\alpha>0}L_{\alpha} \oplus H$  with action $h1=\lambda (h)1$ and $L_{\alpha}1=0, \forall \lambda >0$

I want to prove that $V(\lambda ) \cong U(L)\otimes_{U(L_+)}F_{\lambda}.$

So I define a left L-module homomorphism:

$$\phi : U(L)\to U(L)\otimes_{U(L_+)}F_{\lambda}, U \mapsto U\otimes 1_{\lambda}$$.

It is obvious that $I_{\lambda} \subset Ker\phi$, but I have trouble proving $I_{\lambda} = Ker\phi$.

Can you provide some hints?  Thank you!

Comment: Are $\mathfrak{g}$ and $L$ the same semisimple Lie algebra? Anyway, I'm ashamed to admit how rusty I am. Would using the PBW-basis help here?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. But I am still don't see how the PBW-basis helps here. Can you be more specific?